# Game of life issue with setTimeOut and mode selection

Tags: javascript

A function defined in setTimeOut only runs once in certain situations

I set up 3 inputs in ComboBox by which the user could set the grid size in the game. Selecting a value changes the rows and cols variables respectively, and then reboots the game by calling the init function.
The program starts normally, when I choose a different size the timer does not run the game more than once. When I change the size again it does work. If for example I change the sizes 6 times the game will only work in 3 of the times.

```js
/* Game Of Life Application */
/* ------------------------ */


// initialize global variables
var rows = 55;
var cols = 140;
//initialize 2dim arrays 
var arr;// current generation array
var nextArr; // next generation array
var mode = 0; //game current mode
var timeInMS = 40;
var timer;
//buttons selectors
var randomBtn = document.getElementById("randomBtnId");
var startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtnId");
var clearBtn = document.getElementById("clearBtnId");
var gridSize = document.getElementById("sizeId");
var container = document.getElementById("container");

function remove() {
    let tb = document.querySelector("table");
    tb.outerHTML = "";
}


gridSize.addEventListener("change",function(e) {
    remove();
    if (this.value === "Small") {
        cols = 80;
        rows = 20;
       

    }
    else if (this.value === "Medium") {
        cols = 126;
        rows = 34;  
    }
    else {
        cols = 140;
        rows = 55;
    }
    timer = 0;
    init();
});


//update the visual grid according to the states of the cell - live or dead.
function update() {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            var cell = document.getElementById(i + "_" + j);

            if (arr[i][j] === 0) {
                cell.setAttribute("class", "dead");
            } else {
                cell.setAttribute("class", "live");
            }
        }
    }
}

//copy generation 0 array to generation 1. current arr gets the values of next arr
function copyAndResetGrid() {
    console.log("in the reset grid");
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = nextArr[i][j];
            nextArr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}



//count number of neighbors for every cell - inputs are r - rows , c - columns
function countNeighbors(r, c) {

    let rstart = 0, cstart = 0, rend = rows - 1, cend = cols - 1;
    let count = 0;
    if (r - 1 > 0)
        rstart = r - 1;
    if (c - 1 > 0)
        cstart = c - 1;
    if (r + 1 <= rend)
        rend = r + 1;
    if (c + 1 <= cend)
        cend = c + 1;

    for (let i = rstart; i <= rend; i++) {
        for (let j = cstart; j <= cend; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] === 1)
                count++;
        }
    }

    count -= arr[r][c];
    if (count < 0)
        count = 0;
    // console.log("number of live neighbors at : " + r + "," + c + " is : " + count);
    return count;
}



// calculate next 2dim array (generation 1) according to gameOfLife rules
function calculateNext() {
    let numOfLivesArr = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {



            let currentMode = arr[i][j];
            if (currentMode === 1)
                numOfLivesArr++;
            let count = countNeighbors(i, j);

            if (currentMode === 0 && count === 3) {
                nextArr[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else if (currentMode === 1 && (count < 2 || count > 3)) {
                nextArr[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else {
                nextArr[i][j] = currentMode;
            }
        }
    }
   // console.log("num of lives next: " + numOfLivesArr);
    copyAndResetGrid();
    //update();

}

//run game
function run() {
    calculateNext();
    update();
    timer = setTimeout(run, 1000);
}

//populate the array with random values 0/1
function populateArr() {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            if (arr[i][j] === 1) {
                let cell = document.getElementById(i + "_" + j);
                cell.setAttribute("class", "live");
            }
            else {
                let cell = document.getElementById(i + "_" + j);
                cell.setAttribute("class", "dead");

            }
        }
    }
}
function deleteArr() {

}

//clear array - set 0 values for current and next generations arrays
function clear() {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
            nextArr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    //mode = 0;
}


function buttonsControl() {

    randomBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        clear();
        populateArr();
    });
    startBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (mode == 1) {
            mode = 0;
            startBtn.textContent = "Continue";
           clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        else {
            mode = 1;
            startBtn.textContent = "Pause";
            run();
        }
    });
    clearBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        startBtn.textContent = "Start";
        clear();
        update();
    })
}

//draw table grid in the web page
function drawGrid() {
    let grid = document.getElementById("container");
    let table = document.createElement("table");
    table.setAttribute("class", "center");

    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            let cell = document.createElement("td");
            cell.setAttribute("id", i + "_" + j);
            cell.setAttribute("class", "dead");
            tr.appendChild(cell);
            cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
                if (cell.classList.contains("live")) {
                    cell.setAttribute("class", "dead");
                    arr[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else
                    cell.setAttribute("class", "live");
                arr[i][j] = 1;
            });
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    grid.appendChild(table);
}


//create 2 dim arrays - current and next generations.
function make2DArr() {
    console.log("befire create arr !! ");
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Array(cols);
        nextArr[i] = new Array(cols);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
            nextArr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}


//initial game
function init() {
    arr = new Array(rows);
    nextArr = new Array(rows);

    make2DArr();
    drawGrid();
    buttonsControl();
}

//load init function
window.onload = init();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgba(76, 77, 62, 0.514);
}
.center {
    margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
}
#container {
  
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
}
table {
    border:1px rgb(241, 241, 241) solid;
    border-spacing: 0;
    position: absolute;
    flex:1;
}
.live {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.685);
}
.dead {
    background-color:rgba(228, 228, 241, 0.829);
}


td {
    border:1px rgb(29, 182, 29) solid;
   /* border-radius: 61px;*/
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
 /* button {
     margin-left: 0.5rem;
 } */
 button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  button:hover {
      background-color: rgba(144, 180, 145, 0.596);
      color: rgb(54, 59, 54)
  }
```

```html
<body>

<div class="center">
 <div id="container">
 </div>
 
  <button id="startBtnId"><span>Start</span></button>
  <button id="clearBtnId"><span>Clear</span></button>
  <button id="randomBtnId"><span>Random</span></button>
  <select id="sizeId"> 
   <option value="Big">Big</option>
   <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
   <option value="Small">Small</option>
    </select>
  
</div>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>
```

the timer is work only in even number of mode selection and does not work in odd number of mode selection.
for example , if i changed the mode 4 times : work -> not -> word -> not

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant code and HTML for a [mcve] - for example make2DArr is missing

Comment: I uploaded the missing parts. Thanks

Comment: I do not see anything happen. I just see "In the reset grid"

Comment: I fixed the problem.
Once an option has been selected from the list,  init function was called. Within the function I called for 3 functions that build the arrays, initialize the board and create the button events listeners. The solution is  to build the arrays and initialize the board without create the buttons event listeners again. so i just calld make2darray and drawgrid functions. 
Thank you anyway.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question. It is very localised to you only

Answer (score 0):

Once an option has been selected from the list, init function was called. Within the function I called for 3 functions that build the arrays, initialize the board and create the button events listeners. The solution is to build the arrays and initialize the board without create the buttons event listeners again. so i just calld make2darray and drawgrid functions.